# Using ++ as a prefix to a statement of access through class member not causing an error

Tags: c++

I am kind of confused right now, I was running the following code:

```
std::vector<int> test{1, 5, 10};
++test.at(1); // I'm trying to increment that number 5 to six, which works
std::cout << test.at(1) << std::endl; // Prints out 6 to the console
```

I was expecting it to give me a compiler error because as I had read from about the operator precedence that the `.` (for member access) and the increment operator (`++`) have the same precedence, but they read left to right on a statement, from what I understood anyways. So in the code shown above I thought it would have been equal to saying `(++test).at(1)`, which obviously causes a compiler error. Why isn't that the case even though the associativity is left to right, why is it reading it (from what I think) like this... `++(test.at(1))`? If they have the same precedence wouldn't it, just like in maths, for example, use the `++` first and then the `.`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

True, *postfix* increment (`a++`) and member access (`.`) have the same precedence.

**But you're using *prefix* increment (`++a`).**

Consult [cppreference's precedence chart](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Indeed, `test++.at(i)` would error for the reasons you give, though as readers of the code we would not be in any way surprised in that case.

Comment: Nice concise answer. I would like to add: _Never write code in such a manner, so that others have to consult cppreference's operator precedence chart._

Comment: @nada To be fair; you don't: the fact that the code works is clear enough ;)

Comment: Omg, that was the same page I was reading but I for some reason didn't notice the fact that the prefix one was just below that one, that is stupid from me, thank you for answering my question... I should have paid more attention to detail.

Comment: @Krapnix It's easy to overlook if you're not already thinking about the distinction

Answer (score 0):

Function calls have a higher operator precedence than unary operators like "++".  The function call `at()` gets resolved first, and so the increment operator takes place on what it returns instead of the container.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

EDIT: As Asteroids With Wings pointed out in their answer, only the prefix version of "++" has lower precedence than the function call.  The postfix "++" is at the same level of precedence.

Comment: The question is about the `.` not the `()`

Comment: `()`, `.` and `++` all have the same precedence. Even if `()` had higher `.` happens before call to function `at()`

Comment: Asteroids With Wings -- Whoops, my bad!  Missed that.